# Initialization of bool variables in tensorflow source code

Tags: c++, tensorflow

In tensorflow source code of `tf.ConfigProto` [configproto](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.3/tensorflow/core/protobuf/config.proto), bool type variables are initailized in a strange way :

```
// If true, the allocator does not pre-allocate the entire specified
// GPU memory region, instead starting small and growing as needed.
bool allow_growth = 4;

bool force_gpu_compatible = 8;

bool use_rpc_for_inprocess_master = 1;

bool allow_soft_placement = 7;
...
```

why aren't these bools initailized with `true` and `flase` or just `0` and `1` ?
Although values not 0 is considered as `true` in c++, what is the meaning of doing so? 4, 8, 7, there seems no particular rules of which number to use.

Answer (score 1):

Those are not variable initializations. Those are the tags associated with those fields in the message. For more information, [look here](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#simple).